# MySQL - Keeping track of duplicate record types in a separate column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, window-functions

I have a table called `test` with fields `name`, `sequence_no`, `id1` and `id2` (where the last two are foreign keys).  When I insert a new record, I want to check how many entries there are in the table with the same `id1` and `id2` as the entry I am adding, then I want to use that count+1 as the sequence_no field.  In other words, I want to keep track of how many times I've done a test, and that is identified by the two ids.

I tried to simply do a `sequence_no = (select count(*)+1 from test where id1=newid1 and id2=newid2)` within my insert but I guess I can't select form the table I'm inserting into.

Any ideas on how to do this in a single query? I feel like I should be using ON DUPLICATE, but I'm not sure how to pull this off.

Comment: If you want to add a *new* row, then `on duplicate key update` is not appropriate.  You would need a trigger.  However, this information can usually be calculated when you query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want not to create new rows with the same `(id1, id2)`, but increment `sequence_no` on the existing row, then you can use `on duplicate key`:

```
insert into test (name, sequence_no, id1, id2)
values ( -- your values here --)
on duplicate key update sequence_no = sequence_no + 1
```

This requires a unique key (or primary key constraint) on `(id1, id2)`.

On the other hand if you want some incrementing counter that indicates how many times the same id tuple is met, then it's different. I would not really recommend storing this information in a table, you can compute it on the fly in your queries, typically using window function `row_number()` (available in MySQL 8.0). For this to make sense, you need a column that defines the order of the columns (say `ordering_id`), then you can do:

```
select name, id1, id2, row_number() over(partition by id1, id2 order by ordering_id) sequence_no
from test
```